# preg_match returns null when searching for escaped quotes

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am retrieving a string from my Wordpress database; the string I retrieve is a plain text field where a Wordpress gallery can be added in. Some examples of strings are as follows:

```
<p>test</p><p>[gallery columns=\"2\" ids=\"705,729\"]</p>
<p>[gallery columns=\"2\" ids=\"696,694\"]</p>
<p>test</p>
```

I want to retrieve the numbers that are in the `ids=\"x,x\"` field.

I have the following code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<5; $i++) {
    $result = get_ids_per_category($i, getReferencesMapId());
    ${"idArray".$i} = array();
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        $subject = $res->description;
        $pattern = "/\[(.*?)\]/";
        preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches);
        if ($matches[1]) {
            $subject2 = $matches[1];
            $pattern2 = '/ids=\\"(.*)\\"/';
            preg_match($pattern2, $subject2, $matches2);

            array_push( ${"idArray".$i}, $matches2);
        }
    }

    if (!empty(${"idArray".$i})) {
        ${"finalArray".$i} = array();
        foreach (${"idArray".$i} as $arr) {
            $newarray = explode(",",$arr[1]);
            foreach ($newarray as $item) {
                array_push( ${"finalArray".$i}, $item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I call `var_dump($subject2)`, the following results are returned:

```
\page-referentiemap.php:58:string 'gallery columns=\"2\" ids=\"477,476\"' (length=37)
\page-referentiemap.php:58:string 'gallery columns=\"1\" ids=\"690\"' (length=33)
\page-referentiemap.php:58:string 'gallery ids=\"688,689,690\"' (length=27)
\page-referentiemap.php:58:string 'gallery columns=\"2\" ids=\"697,698,699\"' (length=41)
\page-referentiemap.php:58:string 'gallery ids=\"702,701,703\"' (length=27)
\page-referentiemap.php:58:string 'gallery columns=\"2\" ids=\"696,694\"' (length=37)
```

So far so good, but the line afterwards where I create my regex as follows:

```
preg_match($pattern2, $subject2, $matches2);
```

Will always return a null value in `$matches2`.

I can't remember me changing any code in the last couple of weeks when this did work. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes twice. Once for PHP and once for PCRE. Try this instead:

```
$pattern2 = '/ids=\\\\"(.*)\\\\"/';
```

Though really, it seems like you could make this code a lot simpler. Obviously I can't test fully but it seems like this should work:

```
<?php
$ids = [];
for ($i = 1; $i<5; $i++) {
    $result = get_ids_per_category($i, getReferencesMapId());
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        $subject = $res->description;
        $pattern = '/\[.*?\\bids=\\\\"(\d+),(\d+)\\\\".*?\]/';
        if (preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches)) {
            $ids[$i][] = [$matches[1], $matches[2]];
        }
    }
}

print_r($ids);
```

You do want to stay away from dynamic variable names unless you have a very good reason. Arrays are almost always preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much this did the trick! Can you tell me why dynamic variables are considered bad practice?

Comment: It's a matter of knowing what variables exist at any given time. When you dynamically create variables you're adding an element of uncertainty to your program. Granted, with a simple `for` loop creating a small fixed number of variables, it's not such a big deal. But in this case, what are you going to do with your 5 separate variables? Presumably you'll want to do something with each of them, and arrays can be easily iterated over. And sticking with common programming conventions also makes your code more readable by others. I guess my question would be why use them instead of arrays?